# Is the IVT internally true in Johnstone's topological topos?

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory, reverse-math

By IVT, I mean that for any continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ for which $f(0)\leq 0 \leq f(1)$, there is a $t \in [0,1]$ for which $f(t)=0$. I don't mean any "constructive" substitute, but the previous statement verbatim.

Given that the real numbers $\mathbb R$ form a connected topological space, it would seem reasonable that Johnstone's topological topos should "see" that the real numbers are connected. Should this not manifest in the Intermediate Value Theorem being true in its internal logic? The construction using sheaves over a category $\Sigma$ equipped with a Grothendieck topology seems a bit fearsome, so I don't know how to go about checking this myself. The discussion around sequential and subsequential spaces is yet more bewildering, and I don't know how this can gain me access to the internal logic.

[edit] I also can't get access to Johnstone's 1979 paper, even via Sci-Hub.

Comment: Just as a matter of general background, are you aware of [Paul Taylor's work on constructive analysis](http://paultaylor.eu/ASD/analysis#lamcra), where he studies the IVT and connectedness of $[0,1]$ quite thoroughly. It won't give a direct answer to your question, but is quite informative.

Comment: Also, an immediate observation worth making is that $[0,1]$ is connected in the effective topos, but IVT fails there. You need more than bare connectedness to get IVT.

Comment: I know Paul Taylor personally. And yes, I've seen it. But as I say in my edited question, I am working with the original statement of the IVT, verbatim.

Comment: My gut tells me IVT fails in Johnstone's topos because $t \in [0,1]$ does not vary continuously with $f$. Arbitrarily small changes of $f$ may force $t$ to jump around.

Comment: IVT on its own cannot prove the existence of a discontinuous function as (assuming Countable Choice) it's equivalent to LLPO, which is strictly weaker than WLPO, which is in turn equivalent to the existence of a discontinuous function IIRC.

Comment: I intuitively expect IVT to hold.

Comment: Hmm. You have a good point there.

Comment: 0

I don't have time from a proper answer now, but I expect it follows from what we know about the internal logic: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Johnstone%27s+topological+topos

Comment: Here is the paper by Johnstone: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y_WpbM510XU6zessuiL8vOY9ru-gWopc/view?usp=sharing